# Behavior of backspace, delete, and arrow keys during rename refactor

Tags: python, refactoring, pycharm, rename

Say I want to rename this `really_bad_variable_name` variable (or method or whatever) to `really_good_variable_name`. Typically my caret (cursor) will be positioned somewhere in the middle of that identifier when I call Refactor > Rename...

I want to go to `bad` so I can change that. Now if I try to navigate thereto using the back arrow key on my keyboard, the caret jumps to the beginning of the variable name.

[image]

Similar issue if I try to erase `bad_` using the backspace key: the entire identifier name gets deleted.

Presumably this is because the identifier is "selected" in its entirety by default. Even though this happens every single time, this is never the behavior that I expect from my keyboard keys. So frustrating.

Is there a way to change this so the old name doesn't get selected by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why yes. Yes, there is.

In Settings > Editor > General > Refactorings, un-tick "Preselect old name".

[image]